After Office update, macros are blocked in MS Project
I have MS Project 2019 Pro standalone desktop version. I regularly write and run macros for myself and other users. Two days ago I updated Office to version 2408 (Build 17928.20114). Today I tried to run a macro resident in my Project Global and got a message saying "macros in this project are disabled". Well no, they are not. My Trust setting is to allow all macros to run.
There was an similar issue with Project macros not running on Project Enterprise Global subscription versions of Project with a Windows registry tweak as the fix. I tried that fix but it made no difference on my installation. Perhaps I didn't implement it correctly or there is a different registry tweak required for non-subscription versions.
For reference, I tried running an Excel based macro on an Excel file and that runs fine.
Anyone experience this same problem? Any suggestions for a fix?

Seems there are a couple issues with the release of build .20114 (v2408), and the prior release of v2406. In 2406 it introduced the dialogue box that only gives an option to "Disable Macros" when connecting to Project Online...this thread appears to address that issue: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/project/since-the-update-of-microsoft-project-version-2406-it-is/m-p/4225864 I'm also experiencing the disabled macros in v2408, with no luck on a solution. Perhaps 2406 issue is a clue?

Dan - so far all the "fixes" put out there are okay for subscription versions of Project but they don't work for the standalone desktop version, which is what I have. You can see a full discussion at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/macros-that-we-wrote-in-project-online-in-the/19577051-7a62-4f7b-b80c-58902919108a

Finally got something that actually works. See the thread I referenced above.

For users who have the click-to-run standalone version of Project, the "fix" is to roll updates back to: Version 2407 (Build 16.0.1783020166).
Update 9/6/24. Version 2408 (Build 17928.20114 CTR) is fixed as of 6 Sept, 2024. Local Global based VBA macros run with no error.
